# Float type value is showing in scientific notation

Tags: java, jsp, formatting

The `MMCHAM8` value is `0.0005` and it's data type is float but in screen it is showing scientific notation value like `5.0E-4`

```
<td>
    <input size="5" type="text" name="MMCHAM8" id="MMCHAM8" 
           readonly="readonly" ondblclick="alert(this.value)" 
           class="readonly_field"
           value="${mat.mmValues.MMCHAM8}" />
</td>`
```

Comment: That's scientific notation not hex

Comment: How to fix this issue ,is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't hexdecimal, it's [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). 5.0E-4 means 5 * 10<sup>-4</sup>, which is of course equal 0.0005.

If you want it displayed differently, you could use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
String formatted = df.format(mat.mmValues.MMCHAM8);
```

(and just echo `formatted` in your JSP page)

Comment: Thank you very much @Mureinik

Answer (score 0):

There are many options on how to do it>

1. use `DecimalFormat`:

   ```
   NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
   f.format(mat.mmValues.MMCHAM8);
   ```
2. use `String.format()`:

   ```
   String.format("%.4f", mat.mmValues.MMCHAM8)
   ```
3. use JSTL build in functionality:

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
   <fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="4" value="${mat.mmValues.MMCHAM8}" />
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much @Crazyjavahacking